# How do I create one report from multiple Crystal Report rpt files

Tags: crystal-reports

I have multiple Crystal Reports rpt files and I need to create only one file from them. The file might be any type of rpt, pdf, doc, excel etc.

My problem is that the report files contain subreports and creating a new report and adding them as subreports doesn't seem to work correctly, not showing the data from subreports in subreports.

I know that CR doesn't support subreports in subreports but I need to find a workaround to create only one file from the reports that I have.

Please help !

Comment: I forgot to say that my rpt files are entirely not the same one with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Not a problem.

Step 1: Export all your Crystal Reports to PDF.
Step 2: Use a freeware PDF merger to merge them all together.

I made a quick google search and found http://www.pdfsam.org/.  According to the FAQ, they also have a command-line version (if you need to automate this process, that's the way to go).

Probably the biggest problem you'll have is making all these separate PDFs look like a single document.  You might have to get creative with things like page numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create one report that contains all of the subreports. If there is no link (join) between the data, it should still work.  If there is one (or more) between them, that should be possible too.