# How to create one Crystal report from multiple report files?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have some reports that have subreports in them. I would like to have only one report, not four. The reports does not have the same layout, does not contain the same fields. 
I've tried to add them as subreports into a different new file, but it seems that the data from the subreports in the subreports is not shown.

Is it possible to do this in Crystal? Maybe wrapping the generated files into one? And if so, how do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create one report from multiple Crystal Report rpt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692611/how-do-i-create-one-report-from-multiple-crystal-report-rpt-files)

Answer (score 1):

Alex, welcome to StackOverflow!

There's no need to repeat a question you asked less than a week ago ([How do I create one report from multiple Crystal Report rpt files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692611/how-do-i-create-one-report-from-multiple-crystal-report-rpt-files))

Before you go asking the same question twice, I recommend you look at the suggested answers and respond to them first.